# Telerik grid date column date off by one day

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid in which i have a column where i show DateOfBirth of the user. Below is the partial code of my Telerik Grid column:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DOB).Title("DateofBirth").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

As i have to display on date part on UI i am returning `.Date` from the model  as shown below:

```
public DateTime? DOB
    {
        get
        {
            if (DateOfBirth > DateTime.MinValue)
                return DateOfBirth.Date;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Where DateOfBirth is the date which i get from Database which has Date and Time format. The issue is i see the date off by one day in some scenarios and not always. what could be the cause of that?

For example if the date returned from DB is `06/21/2012 12:00:00 PM` then i am getting it as `06/20/2012`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with the culture-specific datetime.
Are you using different cultures. For example I have ran into scenarios where the database is a universal time and I had to parse the date to get my specific culture.

A few hours change end up changing the date to one day different.

Here is example usage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8

Code Example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dbvalue, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

or System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal to get to local.

Comment: but i am fecthing a column that is already stored in the database. will that make a difference?

Comment: the date is database is `06/21/2012 12:00:00 PM`

Comment: I think what @retslig is asking is whether you know the date stored in the database is a UTC time, or a time local to the machine that entered it

Comment: That is fine, are you using any specific culture in your Telerik grid or just default? Correct Joe.

Comment: @Joeb454 and retslig its UTC time which is stored in database, and I am not using any specific culture in the grid